# Not connecting to RPC server in release mode, but works fine in debug mode

Tags: swift, rpc, combine, transmission-daemon

I have a command line app that does the following:

- downloads an RSS feed with torrent links
- stores it in a sqlite database and tags them as "added" or "ignored"
- connects to a transmission server (in my local network)
- loads items from sqlite marked as "added" and adds to transmission server

The above works fine in debug mode. However, when I build for release and try to run directly or from launchd, it always times out. The most relevant code is in `main.swift` which goes below.

```swift
private func getTransmissionClient() -> Transmission? {
        let client = Transmission(
            baseURL: serverConfig.server,
            username: serverConfig.username,
            password: serverConfig.password)

        var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()
        print("[INFO] Connecting to client")
        client.request(.rpcVersion)
            .sink(
                receiveCompletion: { _ in group.leave() },
                receiveValue: { rpcVersion in
                    print("[INFO]: Successfully Connected! RPC Version: \(rpcVersion)")
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        let wallTimeout = DispatchWallTime.now() +
            DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(serverConfig.secondsTimeout ?? 15)
        let res = group.wait(wallTimeout: wallTimeout)

        if res == DispatchTimeoutResult.success {
            return client
        } else {
            return nil
        }

    }

    public func updateTransmission() throws {

        print("[INFO] [\(Date())] Starting Transmission Update")

        let clientOpt = getTransmissionClient()
        guard let client = clientOpt else {
            print("[ERROR] Failed to connect to transmission client")
            exit(1)
        }

        var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

        let items = try store.getPendingDownload()
        print("[INFO] [\(Date())] Adding \(items.count) new items to transmission")

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        for item in items {

            let linkComponents = "\(item.link)".components(separatedBy: "&")
            assert(linkComponents.count > 0, "Link seems wrong")

            group.enter()
            client.request(.add(url: item.link))
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                    if case let .failure(error) = completion {
                        print("[Failure] \(item.title)")
                        print("[Failure] Details: \(error)")

                    }
                    group.leave()
                }, receiveValue: { _ in
                    print("[Success] \(item.title)")
                    do {
                        try self.store.update(item: item, with: .downloaded)

                    } catch {
                        print("[Error] Couldn't save new status to DB")
                    }
                })
                .store(in: &cancellables)
        }


        let wallTimeout = DispatchWallTime.now() +
            DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(serverConfig.secondsTimeout ?? 15)
        let res = group.wait(wallTimeout: wallTimeout)
        if res == DispatchTimeoutResult.success {
            print("Tasks successfully submitted")
        } else {
            print("Timed out")
            exit(1)
        }
    }
```

Oddly enough, the code seemed to work fine before I added the database. The DispatchGroup was already there, as well as the Transmission-Swift client. I guess something that I did is being "optimized away" by the compiler? This is just speculation though after seeing some other questions on StackOverflow, but I am still not clear on it.

I am using macOS 10.15 and Swift 5.2.2.

Full code available in [github](https://github.com/ataias/TorrentRSS/tree/f0f0166d0aac887aaa7bf5a4245f34913c2dc927) (link to specific commit that has the bug)

Answer (score 0):

I asked for help on Swift Forums at https://forums.swift.org/t/not-connecting-to-rpc-server-in-release-mode-but-works-fine-in-debug-mode/36251 and here is the gist of it:

- Debug vs Release bugs are common in the Apple ecosystem.
- One common reason for the above: the compiler has much more aggressive retain and release patterns in release mode.
- My problem was exactly that: a certain class was being disposed of earlier than it should and it was exactly the cancellable for the subscription, so my server requests were being cancelled in the middle.

This [commit](https://github.com/ataias/TorrentRSS/commit/314cc62890c0152ad35f548642d1d040af816343) fixes it and it basically does the following:

```
diff --git a/Sources/TorrentRSS/TorrentRSS.swift b/Sources/TorrentRSS/TorrentRSS.swift
index 17e1a6b..0b80cd5 100644
--- a/Sources/TorrentRSS/TorrentRSS.swift
+++ b/Sources/TorrentRSS/TorrentRSS.swift
@@ -63,6 +63,10 @@ public struct TorrentRSS {
             DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(serverConfig.secondsTimeout ?? 15)
         let res = group.wait(wallTimeout: wallTimeout)

+        for cancellable in cancellables {
+            cancellable.cancel()
+        }
+
         if res == DispatchTimeoutResult.success {
             return client
         } else {
@@ -117,6 +121,11 @@ public struct TorrentRSS {
         let wallTimeout = DispatchWallTime.now() +
             DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(serverConfig.secondsTimeout ?? 15)
         let res = group.wait(wallTimeout: wallTimeout)
+
+        for cancellable in cancellables {
+            cancellable.cancel()
+        }
+
         if res == DispatchTimeoutResult.success {
             print("Tasks successfully submitted")
         } else {
```

Calling cancellable explicitly avoids the object being disposed of before it should. That specific location is where I meant to dispose of the object, not any sooner.